# What is reference identity in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, operator-keyword

I am searching for difference between operator (==) and the Equals() Method. Many resources say that operator (==) compares reference identity. What is actually reference identity?

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot: string isn't a value type, it's a reference type.

Comment: == is not a reference (pointer) equality for value types (double, int, struct etc), only for reference types, when not overloaded.

Comment: reference identity / equality is described here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons#reference-equality where objects (non-primitive) need to point to same instance. 
bonus
- react: https://medium.com/@jvcjunior/reference-identity-in-javascript-react-performance-12a8354addad
- js: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness
- P.S: not sure why this was closed as duplicate of the other (these 2 questions are neither value nor referentially equivalent completely :p)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to duplicates, I post this answer because the question is more specialized of what I found.

In simple words: reference identity is memory address equality, as two variables points to the same content or not, like a postal address or a glass of water. Because references are hidden pointers to forget to manage them.

GC is also a layer above to facilitate the management of instances of objects in memory and forget to destroy/free those we don't use anymore.

Operator [`==`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators) can be overloaded to compare values instead of references, so there are on `object` [`Equals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.equals) and [`ReferenceEquals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals) methods.

Here are some tutorials:

[C# - Data Types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm)

[C# - Variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_variables.htm)

[Value Type and Reference Type](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type)

[How do I get the reference count of a CLR object?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100811-00/?p=13173)

Comment: `Equals()` can also be overriden (and probably should be if `==` is). `ReferenceEquals()` can not.

Comment: Note that `==` can't be *overridden* (no operators can) - but it can be *overloaded*.

Comment: Also note that .NET doesn't use reference counting, so the second half of your answer is misleading.

Comment: @JonSkeet Learn something today about the ref count, thanks. Answer corrected and updated.

Comment: @OlivierRogier: Java doesn't use reference counting either (at least not in common implementations, as far as I'm aware).